# Locating incorrect force unwrapping location in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

My app crashes every time a table view controller displays its view. The debug console shows the message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Normally XCode would stop at the line of code where the problem happened, but this time I get the following screen with a lot of assembly code instead.[image]

My question is, how can I locate the line of code that caused the crash? I am rather new to iOS development. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: in left sidebar you can see error trace

Comment: @Masiama Oops, didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: I can see that you have got crash on somewhere closure. Please provide some code have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to add exception breakpoint in xcode.

- Move to "Breakpoint Navigator" (Shortcut Command+7).
- Click + symbol at bottom-left corner of navigator.
- You should see "Exception Breakpoint".

By this you would be able to see which line in your code is causing the crash.